# jenkins github webhook error

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration

i'm trying to trigger builds on jenkins when ever a pull request is merged, and trying to add the webhook, which is throwing me the below error.

payload url: http://localhost:8080/job/hook-test/

error: "We couldn’t deliver this payload: Couldn't connect to server "

Answer (score 0):

The URL for the webhook is `localhost`. GitHub is trying call the webhook on itself.

You need to deploy Jenkins in a publicly accesible URL. It won't work with a local Jenkins install in your PC.

`localhost` refers to the address of the current machine. When you type `localhost` in the browser and you access Jenkins, that works because you have Jenkins installed and running in your PC. Access `localhost` from a different machine and you won't be able to access Jenkins. When you tell github to send the webhook to `localhost` it will not try to send it to your machine, instead, it will send the webhook to the same machine in which github server is running, and that machine doesn't have Jenkins installed.

The problem here is `localhost` means something different for you and for github.

To solve this problem, you'll either need to install Jenkins in a public server accesible from internet (so that github can send the webhooks) or use some online service which provides [hosted Jenkins servers](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/98-jenkins-server).

You could also just get a domain and configure it to point to your PC. You would probably need to do some networking configuration but once it's done you (and github) will be able to access your jenkins via `some-domain.example.io` instead of `localhost`. Be careful, you would be making your (I asume personal) PC accesible from the internet, and that has security risks.

If you can afford it I recommend using a server in the cloud to run this. 
Many cloud platforms even provide a quite long free trial period (I know Amazon and Google Cloud do).

Comment: "GitHub is trying call the webhook on itself", it didn't get this point. Could you please elaborate for me. As you mentioned I have installed Jenkins locally on my machine, but github url is different right !

Comment: "The webhook for repo sidhuboby/test-2 on github.com failed to be registered or was removed. More info can be found on the global configuration page. This message will be dismissed if Jenkins receives a PING event from repo webhook or if you add the repo to the ignore list in the global configuration."     my jenkins url : "https://siddhmqljt2017163.trial.cloudbees.net/cjoc/job/hook-test/"

Comment: this time its not my local host !, but, i'm unable to figure out wrong step in hooking

Comment: I can not access the link you posted becuase it requires a login (and DON'T share your credentials here please). I'm not sure exactly what's wrong now as I'm not familiar with cloudbees.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe exactly the steps you are taking. Make sure to make clear which actions you are taking on github and which you are taking on jenkins.

Comment: Jenkins - steps: 1. Created a job in jenkins. 2. source code management is "git" include the repo ssh url and provide credentiald for it. 3. build step "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" after selecting this option i got this error "the webhook for repo username/reponame on github.com failed to be registered or was removed. More info can be found on the global configuration page. This message will be dismissed if Jenkins receives a PING event from repo webhook or if you add the repo to the ignore list in the global configuration."

Comment: github - steps: 1. the repo which i'm using for the jenkins job "settings -> webhooks" here i'm adding the jenkins url and updating the hook. but it was  thowing an error unable to connect to server.

Comment: other - steps: 1. manage jenkins -> configure system -> github server , here i have tested the connection "Credentials verified for user *********, rate limit: 4948"

Comment: What is I am giving ssh key in Git, still I have to expose my machine to internet?